# fromJSON data types

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to use jsonlite package and I have an issue with fromJSON function. I read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2805.pdf and and documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html but I still don't understand the point...

Consider the following json file named JsonFileOne.json:

```
{"cars": [ {"models" : [ {"type":"Fiesta"} ] } ] }
```

When I try command

```
data<-fromJSON(“JsonFileOne.json”)
```

I have that the first array, “cars”, is read as an R data.frame while the second, “models”, is an R list. In addition the object “type” is a list with no names as names(data$cars$models) is NULL.

Why is the first array read as a data.frame and the second one as a list? What is the criterion used by fromJSON to assign an R data type to json entities? Why the object inside the second array is not named “type” but has on the contrary no name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'models' as a list contains data frame in `[[1]]`, so you can get a column name 'type'.

```
names(data$cars$models[[1]])
[1] "type"

data$cars$models[[1]]
    type
1 Fiesta
```

The object in column 'type' is not a list. 'Fiesta' is an observation for a variable 'type' and can be accessed like that:

```
data$cars$models[[1]][1,]
[1] "Fiesta"
```

or

```
data$cars$models[[1]]$type
[1] "Fiesta"
```